# TypeError: response.json is not a function. (In 'response.json()', 'response.json' is undefined)

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, json, react-native

```
fetch('http://localhost:3000/Update_Password', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },

                body: JSON.stringify({
                    id: this.state.User_id,
                    password: this.state.confirm_password,
                }),
            })
            .then(response => response.json())
                .then((res) => {
                    if (res.success === true)
                    {
                        Alert.alert(res.message);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Alert.alert(res.message);
                    }
                })
```

Here is my API
After calling this API I'm getting this error

> TypeError: response.json is not a function. (In 'response.json()',
> 'response.json' is undefined)

[image]

Comment: What came out of your investigation of `response`?

Comment: it supposed to be Success msg that is password updated. but instead getting this error msg as response.json() is not defined

Comment: Hello. You get a response is not defined cause. you don't get any response from the server.  Please also try to catch .

Comment: [Mon Aug 03 2020 17:27:06.970]  LOG  Message which im getting                                   {"details": {"isConnectionExpensive": false}, "isConnected": true, "isInternetReachable": false, "isWifiEnabled": true, "type": "http://172.20.10.2:3000/Update_Password"}

Comment: Is there a chance that your response is a string instead of actual JSON?

Comment: @SamuliHakoniemi Nop I checked.